# Monogame missing method exception with monodevelop

Tags: mono, monodevelop, opentk, monogame

I have follow the installation guide in [here](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/Tutorials%3AInstalling-Prerequisites-on-Linux) but it seems don't working for me. Here is the exception message when I run the program:

`System.MissingMethodException has been thrown`

`Method not found: 'OpenTK.NativeWindow.set_CursorVisible'.`

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'OpenTK.NativeWindow.set_CursorVisible'.
 at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamePlatform.set_IsMouseVisible (Boolean value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGamePlatform..ctor (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamePlatform.Create (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 at testing.Game1..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 at testing.Program.Main () [0x00000] in /home/user/testing/testing/Program.cs:20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by download `monodevelop-monogame` dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can just install using the installer available here http://monogame.codeplex.com/releases/view/102870

Then create a new project from Visual Studio

Comment: What kind of project are you newing up?